# Google App Engine - Node.js - Outbound https request not sent from request handler

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, https

I'm running a node express server on GAE flexible environment. One of my endpoint routes should, in addition to other things, send a push notification to some users. I don't want the requesting user to wait for the external Pushwoosh push API response before continuing/getting a response, so I am calling the below code in a separate function outside of my initial request/response promise-chain. So that when this code sends the async request to Pushwoosh, my users request-response promise chain continues off on it's own and leaves the remote API call to finish by itself.

I have tested this code running node locally, and it works fine. When I deploy this exact same code to GAE, the Pushwoosh request is never sent for some reason. I cannot see any console.log of neither response or error. I have verified that all request data is correct.

What is causing this request to not being sent? Node version is 6.9.4.

```
var https = require('https');

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
};

var options = {
    host: 'cp.pushwoosh.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/json/1.3/createMessage',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

var message = {
    request: {
        application: process.env.PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID,
        auth: process.env.PUSHWOOSH_REST_API_KEY,
        notifications: [{
            send_date: 'now',
            ignore_user_timezone: true,
            content: 'test',
            ios_badges:'+1',
            android_badges:'+1',
            android_priority: 2,
            android_vibration: 1,
            data:{
                key: 'value'
            }
        }]
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Response:');
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(e);
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(message));
req.end();
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this? Similar problem for me with Google Cloud Functions...